# how to sum the array time

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3, php-5.3

I have an array like this. I need to add the total length of time in all the occurances of the array. so in the example below it will be 00:04:03 + 00:06:03 = 00:10:06

```
Array
(
  [4894] => Array
  (
    [0] => Array
    (
      [Informative] => Array
      (
        [id] => 109
      )     
      [jQuery] => Array
      (
        [length] => 00:04:03
        [alignment] => 8
      )
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
      [Informative] => Array
      (
        [id] => 110
      )     
      [jQuery] => Array
      (
        [length] => 00:06:03
        [alignment] => 8
      )
    )
```

how can I add length in the above array so that it still is a time and adds as time.

thanks

Comment: What have you tried? It should be a simple matter of parsing it and converting to seconds then formatting that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$totalTimeSecs = 0;
foreach ($array as $l1) { // Loop outer array
  foreach ($l1 as $l2) { // Loop inner arrays
    if (isset($l2['jQuery']['length'])) { // Check this item has a length
      list($hours,$mins,$secs) = explode(':',$l2['jQuery']['length']); // Split into H:m:s
      $totalTimeSecs += (int) ltrim($secs,'0'); // Add seconds to total
      $totalTimeSecs += ((int) ltrim($mins,'0')) * 60; // Add minutes to total
      $totalTimeSecs += ((int) ltrim($hours,'0')) * 3600; // Add hours to total
    }
  }
}
echo "Total seconds: $totalTimeSecs<br />\n";

$hours = str_pad(floor($totalTimeSecs / 3600),2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
$mins = str_pad(floor(($totalTimeSecs % 3600) / 60),2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
$secs = str_pad($totalTimeSecs % 60,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo "Total time string: $hours:$mins:$secs";
```

[See it working](http://codepad.org/IRJGTRXi)

Answer (score 0):

1. To find `sum of seconds`, iterate through your array and calculate `total seconds` from the time for each entry i.e. 3600*hour + 60*min + sec.
2. Convert `sum of seconds` to time representation:

> ```
> sumSecs = ...
> hour = sumSecs / 3600
> min = (sumSecs mod 3600) / 60
> sec = sumSecs mod 60
> ```