# php sum time with variable in while loop

Tags: php, mysql

php sum variable in while loop
I have to "sum" variable's values in while, here us my example :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $working_hour= $row[working_hour];
}
```

The code above will output if I put `echo $working_hour;` for example:
01:00:03, 01:03:04, 01:10:15
I want something like : sum($working_hour) or array_sum($working_hour) to count all the results of while loop. So, that i want to count: 01:00:03, 01:03:04, 01:10:15= 03:13:22
I try this way :

```
$total_working_hour=’00:00:00’;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $working_hour= $row[working_hour];
  $total_working_hour+= $working_hour;
}

Echo $total_working_hour;
```

The code above provide output as:

```
03
```

How can I do it with php?
Thanks

Comment: Can you share the query with us?

Comment: I just want to mention ***as a very important side note that you should not be using mysql_* functions but should instead use PDO or MySQLi.*** The old mysql extension has been deprecated for years and was removed from PHP 7. Please see [Choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) in the manual for more information on how to update your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $hours=0;$min=0;$sec=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $working_hour= $row[working_hour];
        $arr=explode(':',$working_hour);
        $hours=$hours+$arr[0];
        $min=$min+$arr[1];
       if($min>60){$hours++;$min=$min-60;}
        $sec=$sec+$arr[2];
        if($sec>60){$min++;$sec=$sec-60;}
    }
    echo 'Total working hours='.$hours.':'.$min.':'.$sec;
```

Comment: Thank Very much,Satty

Answer (score 0):

I used the answer here ([how to sum the array time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650821/how-to-sum-the-array-time)) and created the following function:

```
  function addTime($a, $b) {
    $array = [$a, $b];
    $totalTimeSecs = 0;
    foreach ($array as $time) { // Loop outer array
      list($hours,$mins,$secs) = explode(':',$time); // Split into H:m:s
      $totalTimeSecs += (int) ltrim($secs,'0'); // Add seconds to total
      $totalTimeSecs += ((int) ltrim($mins,'0')) * 60; // Add minutes to total
      $totalTimeSecs += ((int) ltrim($hours,'0')) * 3600; // Add hours to total
    }

    $hours = str_pad(floor($totalTimeSecs / 3600),2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $mins = str_pad(floor(($totalTimeSecs % 3600) / 60),2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $secs = str_pad($totalTimeSecs % 60,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return "$hours:$mins:$secs";
  }
```

So you can use this and replace

```
$total_working_hour+= $working_hour;
```

with

```
$total_working_hour = addTime($total_working_hour, $working_hour);
```

Comment: Thank Very much,Webinan

Comment: @ARBhuiyan you're welcome, consider upvote / accept if the answer is useful.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `$row["working_hour"]` is clearly a string. So saying something like `"01:00:03" + "01:03:04"` clearly makes no sense. PHP assumes that what you meant to do was cast the strings to integers first and then add them together. The result of that is not what you're actually after.

Instead, you want to convert a string like `"01:00:03"` to an normalized integer value, like number of seconds, that can be added together and then converted back to a string value.

So to get the normalized value of the string as an integer in seconds you need a function like this...

```
function convertStringToNumSeconds($string) {
    list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(":", $string, 3);
    $totalSeconds = 0;
    $totalSeconds += $hours * 3600; // There are 3600 seconds in an hour
    $totalSeconds += $minutes * 60; // There are 60 seconds in a minute
    $totalSeconds += $seconds; // There is 1 second in a second
    return $totalSeconds;
}
```

Then to convert the seconds back to a formatted string you can do the opposite...

```
function secondsToString($seconds) {
    $hours = (int) floor($seconds / 3600);
    $seconds -= $hours * 3600;
    $minutes = (int) floor($seconds / 60);
    $seconds -= $minutes * 60;
    return sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
}
```

Now in your loop you can actually do something like this...

```
$totalWork = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $totalWork += convertStringToNumSeconds($row["working_hour"]);
}
echo secondsToString($totalWork); // You should get your expected result
```

Comment: I just want to mention ***as a very important side note that you should not be using mysql_* functions but should instead use PDO or MySQLi.*** The old mysql extension has been deprecated for years and was removed from PHP 7. Please see [Choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) in the manual for more information on how to update your code.

Comment: Thank Very much,Sherif

Answer (score 0):

If the format in your example is fix, you can work with DateTime-Object and Date-Interval as well like this... (for further information to DateInterval, have a look at the PHP-Docu)

```
    $dt = new \DateTime('00:00:00');
    foreach ($dbRows as $row) {

        $time = $row['working_hour'];
        $timeSplit = explode(':', $time);
        $interval = new \DateInterval(
            'P0Y0DT'.$timeSplit[0].'H'.
            $timeSplit[1].'M'.$timeSplit[2].'S'
        );
        $dt->add($interval);
    }

    echo $dt->format('H:i:s'); // Output: 03:13:22
```

Comment: Thank Very much,jiGL